# Persistent data after application removal

Tags: applications, uninstallation

After uninstalling some apps, some data remain

Where are these files located ? All of them

Where is licensing data stored ?

**SD maid** nor **Revo Uninstaller Mobile** could find anything, but data DO remain

Example:

OCR Text scanner

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.offline.ocr.english.image.to.text

I've uninstalled many times, including with the mentioned tools

The whole history, pictures and licensing information (don't know if linked to google) are kept

Comment: What app you are talking about in specific and how do you know that data is stored? Please give some details so that it's easy to explain. Are you talking about app's license used by PlayStore?

Comment: Example added to the body of the OP

Comment: I installed your linked app, used it a bit and uninstalled. As expected, uninstalling removed `/data/data/com.offline.ocr.english.image.to.text` and `/sdcard/Android/data/com.offline.ocr.english.image.to.text` but retained folders `/sdcard/OCRApp` and `/sdcard/OCRTextScanner` which I deleted manually. After reinstallation, no data persists. However I didn't test app with network connection. May be the app backs up its data to servers.